# 12 pin circular connector with twist lock What kind of conn it is?

Tags: connector

I'm trying to find whose product this. I have an another one with yellow and black twist lock. So might be the twist lock color is variable. 
Anybody can send an offer or anybody recognize it?
Thank You!

[image: from side]

[image: from back]

[image: from front]
[image: from front with pins]

Comment: What kind of application was this used with? Factory automation, Automotive, Military Communication Equipment, RC cars? Knowing which direction to roughly look is half the solution to sourcing something.

Comment: I have no idea.